# p4 fstat doesn't list headChange

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to use p4 fstat command to retrieve the change id where the file was last time submitted into the depot. 
Here is the output:

```
p4 fstat File.cs
... depotFile //csharpDepot/src/File.cs
... clientFile C:/space/codereviewtests/perforce/csharpWorkspace\src\File.cs
... haveRev 4
... action edit
... change default
... type text
... actionOwner user1
... ... otherOpen0 user1@mystorage
... ... otherAction0 edit
... ... otherChange0 default
... ... otherOpen 1
```

I can see the change list history in p4v with no problem for the file. What can be the reason headChange is not listed with p4 fstat command?

This is the output from `p4 filelog File.cs`

```
//csharpDepot/src/File.cs
... #5 change 59 edit on 2013/03/22 by user1@csharpWorkSpace (text) 'dd '
... #4 change 57 edit on 2013/03/17 by user1@csharpWorkSpace (text) 'second'
... #3 change 56 edit on 2013/03/17 by user1@csharpWorkSpace (text) 'commit '
... #2 change 54 edit on 2013/03/17 by user1@csharpWorkSpace (text) 'commit changes '
... #1 change 53 add on 2013/03/17 by user1@csharpWorkSpace (text) 'initial commit '
```

Another problem here is that p4 print tells me File.cs - no such file. It is bad as I need to download last submitted revision content. 
Thanks!

Comment: What does 'p4 filelog File.cs' say?

Comment: p4 filelog does list the change lists,  ``p4 filelog File.cs
    //csharpDepot/src/File.cs
    ... #5 change 59 edit on 2013/03/22 by user1@csharpWorkSpace (text) 'dd '
    ... #4 change 57 edit on 2013/03/17 by user1@csharpWorkSpace (text) 'second'
    ... #3 change 56 edit on 2013/03/17 by user1@csharpWorkSpace (text) 'commit  '
    ... #2 change 54 edit on 2013/03/17 by user1@csharpWorkSpace (text) 'commit changes  '
    ... #1 change 53 add on 2013/03/17 by user1@csharpWorkSpace (text) 'initial commit ' ``

Comment: ``p4 changes File.cs`` doesn`t list anything though

Comment: An interesting observation I see is that all the `head*` fields - `headAction`, `headType`, `headTime`, `headRev`, `headChange`, `headModTime` are missing in the output. And `p4 help fstat` says, these fields are displayed only `if in depot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client view mapping was set up incorrectly.
I could figure it out when tried to call `p4 fstat` and `p4 print` using depot path.
These two commands worked fine when specified depot path.
After view mapping fix the commands work fine with the local paths as well.